# How to write a selector to find the first "input" after an element with class "x"

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors

I want to choose the first `input` box right after the element that has style class "x". The element I want to choose is *not* a child of that `input` box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `nextAll` in conjunction with `:first`. `.siblings()` will also select elements before the element with class `x`.

```
$(".x").nextAll("input:first")
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out:

```
$(".x").siblings("input:first")
```